# In Android Studio my .js file reverts to previously changed code after running the app

Tags: android, android-studio

As mentioned in the title, my code modifications are being reverted after clicking "Run 'app'".

To explain further, I have a .js file in which this has been occurring, and for testing purposes I have focused on simply two lines of code:

```
CreateBoxAsync(scene).then(function () {
//CreateSpheresAsync(scene).then(function () {
```

As it stands, I want to make the simple change of commenting `CreateBoxAsync`, and uncommenting `CreateSpheresAsync`. Once I have edited my code to reflect this wanted change, I save progress and run the app. After I do this, the app successfully launches on my physical device (samsung SM-T870), however, the function called is the one creating the box, `CreateBoxAsync`. When checking the .js file in Android Studio again, it has also reverted to how the code is displayed in the above code fragment.

I have so far tried to 'Clean Project', then making the mentioned code changes and then 'Make Project' before trying to run the app once more. The result is that when pressing 'Make Project' the code is reverted whilst the project is being built.

**Other notable observations:**

Sometimes when saving the .js file a pop-up appears mentioning a '**File Cache Conflict**', it had the options of '**Load File System Changes**' and '**Keep Memory Changes**' (see image below). I want to keep the memory changes in this instance, however even after selecting this option code continues to be reverted when I run the application.

[image: File Cache Conflict Message]

I was also unsure if it had to do with the .js file being located in the 'assets' folder in the file tree, could it be possible it is being cached when stored here? Example of this file path is:
android>app>assets>Scripts>experience.js

Comment: Is the file open in another program that might do autosaving? This might be the problem.

Comment: @MennoSpijker I can confirm that it isn't open elsewhere. I have also tried closing Android Studio, opening the file elsewhere to edit and save, closing the editor and then finally relaunching Android Studio, only for it to revert as it has before.